# Mobile device contorts a page on my site

Tags: html, css

Im almost done finishing building this site for a client but everytime i view the fleet page in mobile its broken the pictures stack instead of being inline. could anyone help me.

to view what im talking about visit www.bayareasedans.com on your cellphone and click the fleet page or http://mobiletest.me/htc_one_emulator/#u=http://www.bayareasedans.com and click the fleet page.

```
<div style="width: 960px;" class="fleet">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Mercedes Benz S550</th>
                <th>Chevy Suburban SUV</th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="pics/merc550small.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="pics/suburbansmall.png"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Lincoln Town Car Sedan</th>
                <th>Lincoln Town Car Stretch</th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="pics/towncar_blacksmall.jpg"/></td>
                <td><img src="pics/limo_blacksmall.jpg"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

table {
margin: 25px auto;
}

.fleet th {
font-family: 'oxygenregular';
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fleet img{
width: 473px;
height: 264px;
}
```

you can view the full sites code at: https://github.com/salehkaddoura/MetroSedans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to be using any **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** in your CSS to alter the layout when a mobile device views the page. You have the appropriate `<meta name="Viewport">` tag, but nothing else. This effects the entire website, not just the Fleets page.

On a related note, by placing your basic CSS in multiple stylesheets, you are adding page load time and load on the server every time someone visits your site. You could avoid this by compiling them into a single stylesheet.